# argv having issues reading in * character from console input in C

Tags: c, math, stderr, argv

I am trying to read:
 (int 1) operator (int 2)  or  returnType (int 1) operator (int 2)
, a total of 4 - 5 arguments, from the console and perform a mathematical operator 
based on the input. It works for everything except * (for multiplication). It is returning an error in my code from the following error catch:

```
if(argc == 4){
    do this...
}
else if{ argc == 5){
    do this...
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr,"usage error, invalid arguments\n");
    return 3;
}
```

It is hitting this error no matter what I put in. If I do "test X string1 * string2" or "test string1 * string2" either way, 4 or 5 arguments, it is giving me an error (also tossing arguments for 1-10 arguments, just tested to see). I don't think that more code will be needed for this since it is likely just having to manipulate the input of * (special character?) but if more code is needed let me know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's working just fine. Your shell is globbing the wildcard. Quote it.

```
./someprogram a '*' b
```

Comment: Or use `\*` or use `set -o noglob`

Comment: See I thought so too, the problem I have is that the professor is running a script that runs the code as I input it (no '' or \ or anything, just *). Is that even possible to detect within the code. It seems like it would always jumble it up, no?

Comment: Thumbs up to you sir. Wondered why I haven't been able to find an answer for 3 days. Thanks for the help everyone